# Wordpress - New Post Published Notifications count

Tags: wordpress, cookies, notifications

I'm trying to get a simple Notifications on front-end when new post is published without using any plugins, this code is working, but how can i make notifications as a counter of the new posts instead of (If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.) and the ( Hide ) button to be like a Bell to collect the notifications count number.

[image]

Another problem is Cookie removing the old notification if there are new notification, so i need to keep the counter until each user click on it.

hide.notification.bar.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#notification_hide_button").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".notifications_bar").hide();

        if ($.cookie( 'hide_post_cookie' ) ) { 
            $.cookie( 'hide_post_cookie', null ) 
        }
        var post_id = parseInt( cookie_Data.post_id, 10 );

        $.cookie( 'hide_post_cookie', post_id, { expires: 2, path: '/' } );

    });

});
```

Function.php

```
function enqueue_cookie_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-cookie', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-js/jquery.cookie.js', array( 'jquery' ), '' , true );
    wp_register_script( 'set-cookie-option', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-js/hide.notification.bar.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-cookie'), '' , true );

    $cookie_data = array(
        'post_id' => get_option( 'new_post_notification' )->ID
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'set-cookie-option', 'cookie_Data', $cookie_data ); // this one do the magic

    wp_enqueue_script( 'set-cookie-option' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_cookie_scripts' );

add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
    //Check if our post status then execute our code
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' ) {
        if ( get_option( 'new_post_notification' ) !== false ) {

            // The option already exists, so we just update it.
            update_option( 'new_post_notification', $post );

        } else {

            add_option( 'new_post_notification', $post );

        }
    }

}, 10, 3 );

function get_new_post_notification_bar() {

    // Get the new_post_notification which holds the newest post
    $notification   = get_option( 'new_post_notification' );

    // Get the post ID saved in the cookie
    $cookie_post_ID = isset( $_COOKIE['hide_post_cookie'] ) ? (int) $_COOKIE['hide_post_cookie'] : false; 

    $output = '';

    if( false != $notification ) {

        //First check if we have a cookie, if not, show the notification bar
        // If a cookie is set, do not display the notification bar
        if( false === $cookie_post_ID ) {

            //Get the post's gmt date. This can be changed to post_date
            $post_date = strtotime( $notification->post_date_gmt );

            //Get the current gmt time
            $todays_date = current_time( 'timestamp', true );

            //Set the expiry time to two days after the posts is published
            $expiry_date = strtotime( '+2 day', $post_date );

            //Show the notification bar if the expiry date is not yet reached
            if( $expiry_date > $todays_date ) { 

                $output .= '<div class="notifications_bar">';
                $output .= 'If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<button id="notification_hide_button">';
                $output .= 'Hide';
                $output .= '</button>';

            }

        }else{

            /**
             * If a cookie is set, check the cookie value against the post id set as last post
             * If the two don't match, delete the cookie and show the notification bar if a new post is published
             * This code only run once, that is when a cookie is still set, and new post is published within the time
             * in which the cookie is still set
            */ 
            if( (int) $notification->ID !== $cookie_post_ID ) {

                ?>
                    <script>
                        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                            $.removeCookie('hide_post_cookie', { path: '/' });

                        });
                    </script>
                <?php

                $output .= '<div class="notifications_bar">';
                $output .= 'If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<button id="notification_hide_button">';
                $output .= 'Hide';
                $output .= '</button>';

            }

        }   

    }

    return $output;

}
```

Comment: maybe you have to add a custom field on the post so you can check if it has been seen. It woun't be easy to do and control... but it's the way ;)

Comment: Thanks ill try it, but please can you tell me how can i avoid the cookie from deleting old notification! I want to keep all notifications until click on hide button or after 2 days like what i did.